# How to Inject multiple mock promises to unit test the fetch in JS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jest-fetch-mock

I'm trying to setup unit tests for the api calls in my JS project.
Able to set it up for a single API call, using the following format

```
describe('Token refresh success', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    global.fetch = () =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(mockTokenCreateSuccess),
      })
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    global.fetch = unmockedFetch
  })

  test('testTokenRefreshSuccess', async () => {
    const tokenData = await c.tokenRefresh();
    expect(tokenData.access_token).toEqual('SYoHdm4yw');
    expect(tokenData.refresh_token).toEqual('QxJ3yEgX4NThbTE66u7lshWTpQkRBilq');
  });
})
```

Now this format works great, and I can create individual tests by injecting one promise.

Now, there is a case I want to unit test where a particular API call is made twice. I need to inject fail response the first time, and success response the second time.

I tried the following approach, but did not work:

```
describe('Token refresh trigger as expected on create token fail', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    global.fetch = () => [
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.reject(mockError(400)),
      }),
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(mockTokenCreateSuccess),
      })
    ] 
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    global.fetch = unmockedFetch
  })

  test('testTokenRefreshTriggerOnTokenCreateFail', async () => {
    const tokenData = await c.tokenRefresh();
    expect(tokenData.access_token).toEqual('jkhjk');
    expect(tokenData.refresh_token).toEqual('dfdfdf');
  });
})
```

and my tokenRefresh() function is supposed to get called 2 times if it gets 400 error.

```
async tokenRefresh(retryCount = 0) {
        console.log('tokenRefresh');

        const request = this.getTokenRefreshRequest();
        try {
            const response = await this.fetchData(request);
            console.log('token refresh success', response);
            return { access_token, refresh_token };
        } catch (err) {
            if ((err.status == 400 || err.status == 401) && retryCount < 2) {
                await this.tokenRefresh(retryCount++);
            } else {
                throw new Error(`unable to refresh a token from API ${err.status}`);
            }
        }
    };
```

I'm able to verify that by using single promise

```
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.reject(mockError(400)),
  })
```

the tokenRefresh() gets called again as expected, but in the second time I could not figure out how to pass the success promise, at the moment it fails the second time too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a working combination

```
beforeAll(() => {
    global.fetch = fetchMock.mockRejectOnce(customError) // makes sure first api call fails
    .mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(successResponse)) // makes sure second api call succeeds
  })
```

This made my test pass